# Javascript Async: Rerun the function on map

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

#### Problem with map

I want to map the array, that reruns the function `tree(...)`. However, it returns a array of promises which is not what i expected. I need it to be async.

What i expect to return is a array with this format:

{
  name: '',
  path: '',
  type: '',
  ext: '',
  children: [
     ... same array with all the files in the directory
  ]
}

```js
var Os = require('os')
var Path = require('path')
var Fs = require('fs')

const P = Path.join(Os.homedir(), 'Desktop', 'Devior', 'Fixture');

class Tree {
 constructor(path) {
  this.path = path
  this.tree(path)
 }
 async tree (path) {
  let name = Path.basename(path)
  let item = { path, name }
  let stats = await this.stats_safe()

  if(stats.isFile()) {
   let ext = Path.extname(path).toLowerCase()

   item.extension = ext
   item.type = 'file'
  }
  else if(stats.isDirectory()) {
   let data = await this.readdir_safe()

   item.children = data
    .map(child => this.tree(Path.join(path, child)))
    .filter(e => !!e)
   item.type = 'directory'
  }
  else { return null }
  return item
 }


 // Utils

 async stats_safe() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   Fs.stat(this.path, (err, stats) => {
    if(err) reject(err)
    resolve(stats)
   })
  })
 }
 async readdir_safe() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   Fs.readdir(this.path, (err, data) => {
    if(err && err.code !== 'EACCES')
     resolve(null)
    if(err) reject(err)
    resolve(data)
   })
  })
 }
}



new Tree(P)
```

Comment: did my answer helped you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all#Asynchronicity_or_synchronicity_of_Promise.all) to wait until all of those promisses will resolve, and then return array of values. Something like this should work:

```
item.children = await Promise.all(data
    .map(async (child) => await this.tree(Path.join(path, child)))
```

Also [here](http://thecodebarbarian.com/basic-functional-programming-with-async-await.html) is some info about how to use map and filter with arrays of promises. Worth to take a look